# Kotlin RadioButton comparison Android

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I'm trying to get the selected Radio Button by the user and compare their selection to the correct answer.
For example You have 4 options and 1 of them is true, how to compare them?
Below is my Kotlin code

```
var rganswers1 = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.rganswers1)
        var btnSubmit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmit)

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var rbq1a1 = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rbq1a1)
            var rbq1a2 = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rbq1a2)
            var rbq1a3 = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rbq1a3)
            var rbq1a4 = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rbq1a4)

            var selectedAnswer = rganswers1.checkedRadioButtonId
            if (selectedAnswer.equals(rbq1a3)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in the if statement was comparing the view ID to the view itself, so they can never be equal.

However, you don't need to list out all those radio button views, or have exhaustive when statements. Your entire code can be simplified to:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
    val response = when(rganswers1.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        R.id.rbq1a3 -> "Correct" 
        else -> "false"
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Just need to use `when()` statement and give each answer a return value.

```
var rganswers1 = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.rganswers1)
        var btnSubmit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmit)

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


            var selectedAnswer = rganswers1.checkedRadioButtonId

            when(selectedAnswer){
                R.id.rbq1a1 ->{Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                R.id.rbq1a2 ->{Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                R.id.rbq1a3 ->{Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                R.id.rbq1a4 ->{Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
            }


        })
```

Comment: Your original code was better, if you simply replaced `selectedAnswer.equals(rbq1a3)` with `selectedAnswer.equals(R.id.rbq1a3)` (more properly `selectedAnswer == R.id.rbq1a3`).  This is very verbose and repetitive code. If you find yourself copy-pasting lines of code more than once and making small changes, you should rethink how to do it with less repetition so it is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm just a newbie who is trying to learn.
I will keep that in mind!